# How to use grep to output unique lines of code from a file?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a large log file that contains lines such as:

```
82.117.22.206 - - [08/Mar/2013:20:36:42 +0000] "GET /key/0/www.mysite.org.uk/ HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "-"
```

And i want to extract from each line that matches the above pattern only the ip `82.117.22.206` followed by a space and the text `www.mysite.org.uk` from it. The ip and text can differ. So given the above line the line in the output file would be:

```
82.117.22.206 www.mysite.org.uk
```

How can I use grep or other commands in bash to make the output unique so that the output file won't contain two identical lines? Can someone refer me to a good place to start learnning more about this kind of shell scripting?

Comment: ip is easy: `cat log|awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq`. extracting that hostname will be a harder. is it the uri always `/key/0/hostname_goes_here`?

Comment: @MarcB always between `/key/0/` and another dash `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With perl you can capture the parts

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if (m/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s+-\s+-\s+\[.+?\]\s+\"GET\s+\/key\/0\/(.+?)\//) {
    print "$1 $2\n";
}
```

and call this as

```
perl -n script.pl logfile.txt | sort -u
```

This extracts the needed fields, sorts and eliminates duplicate lines.

Comment: I get nothing as an output

Comment: @Tom I tested this with your example as input and it works as expected. If you get no output, your logfile might be empty or the pattern is different from what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

if you figure out the regex to use, you could do something like:

```
echo "Hello World" | grep "Hell" | sed 's/\(Hell\).*\(World\)/\1 \2/'
```

only, you'd cat your log, instead of echoing a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po "^[\d.]*|[^/]*(?=/ HTTP)" file|sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```