# Use perl to output unique lines from a log file?

Tags: perl, shell

In a previous question I asked how to output from a log file depending on a regex:
[How to use grep to output unique lines of code from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303071/how-to-use-grep-to-output-unique-lines-of-code-from-a-file#15303242)

Now the script that I'm using now outputs lists such as:

```
11.12.13.14 www.mydomain.org.uk
11.12.13.16 www.mydomain.org.uk
105.2.3.1 www.myseconddomain.org.uk
105.2.3.1 myseconddomain.org.uk
```

What I would like to do is erase lines that share the same C class ip. So I would want to tweak the previous answer to output:

```
11.12.13.14 www.mydomain.org.uk
105.2.3.1 www.myseconddomain.org.uk
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: What happened to `11.12.13.16`?

Comment: Are you particular about perl or you could do with shell commands like sed or awk ?

Comment: It shares the same C class as 11.12.13.14 so it should be skipped

Comment: @Tuxdude anything goes but please view the previous question because it is based on it

Comment: how likely is it that your script may need to support ipv6 input?

Comment: @ysth highly unlikely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Perl one-liner that should do the trick:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^((\d+\.){3})/ and not $seen{$1}++' < logfile.txt
```

The regexp `/^((\d+\.){3}/` matches the first three octets of the IP (or, to be exact, three sequences of one or more digits, each followed by a period, at the beginning of the line) and captures them in `$1`.  The expression `$seen{$1}++` then increments the corresponding element in the hash `%seen` (creating it if needed) and returns the value *before* the increment (which will thus be false if and only if that value of `$1` has not been seen before).

Comment: `Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^( <-- HERE (\d+\.){3}/ at -e line 1`

Answer (score 0):

try awk one-liner:

```
awk '!a[$1]++ && !b[$2]++' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo "11.12.13.14 www.mydomain.org.uk
11.12.13.16 www.mydomain.org.uk
105.2.3.1 www.myseconddomain.org.uk
105.2.3.1 myseconddomain.org.uk"|awk '!a[$1]++ && !b[$2]++'
11.12.13.14 www.mydomain.org.uk
105.2.3.1 www.myseconddomain.org.uk
```

Comment: It fails on `94.134.40.100 mydomain.com
94.134.40.241 www.mydomain.com`

Comment: @Tom : please update your sample data in your question to include these cases. good luck.